# Kernel Extensions Fail To Load On Totally Fresh High Sierra Install

Tags: macos, driver, macos-high-sierra, xnu

I strongly suspect that this is a High Sierra bug but really I don't know.  I hope to fix this myself but I don't have a clue.

===

Edit: I now think this a bug in [User-Approved Kernel Extension Loading](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2459/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017658).  The kexts will load when permission is granted in Security Preferences, but they won't load after a reboot.

I filed a bug which Apple people may find [in Radar](http://rdar://39219050)

===

My driver stack has three kernel extensions.  Normally two of them always load while the third loads when my USB dongle is attached.

If I install this product on a totally clean High Sierra install, then none of them will load after rebooting.  This persists through many reboots.

Forcing a kext cache rebuild has no effect:

`$ sudo touch /System/Library/Extensions`

However if High Sierra has been used for a while, or if High Sierra is installed on top of Sierra, then the kernel extensions load just fine.

My client is a fabless semiconductor firm; their customers are all peripherals manufacturers.  This bug was found by a customer in a product that until now had been working really, really well.

Please help me, O Obi Wan K'Stackoverflow'i.  You're my only hope!

Dumbfoundedly,

Mike